# Sorting Dates and amount of values in a given date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Im trying to display a graph from dataframe:

```
    created_date    unique_key
0   2019    42065237
1   2011    22253407
2   2011    22254169
```

For X axis I want Dates in sorted order, for Y axis I want Total of unique keys per year.

here is what i have tried:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
x_data,y_data = (time_vs_heat_complaints_df['created_date'].values,time_vs_heat_complaints_df['unique_key'].values)
plt.plot(x_data,y_data, 'ro')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('# of Heat/Hot Water Complaints')
plt.show()
```

this was my result, its a mess.

[image]

For X axis I want Dates in sorted order, for Y axis I want Total of unique keys per year. and for some reason its just showing from  1-4 it should be in the hundreds of thousands (y axis)

I specifically need to define xdata, and ydata to get my independent and dependent variables for making a prediction, the answer does not work in this case because here is what I tried using his answer:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
x_data,y_data = (pluto_df['created_date'].values,pluto_df.groupby('created_date')['HEAT/HOT WATER'].size())
plt.plot(x_data,y_data, 'ro')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Complaints')
plt.show()
```

and I received an error

```
 x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1289842,) and (9,)
```

Comment: Can you post a little more data to work on it.

Comment: Total of: 452319 Heat Hot water Complaints in: 10 Years, so unique_key is 452,319 and im trying to get this to show in y axis

Comment: try: `time_vs_heat_complaints_df.groupby('created_date').unique_key.size()`.

Comment: i get error x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (452319,)

Comment: What do you get of you remove .values?

Comment: this is what i get : https://i.gyazo.com/cc3e25f1107d0d8d10af0bb1744130f1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
s = df.groupby('created_date').unique_key.size()
x_data, y_data = s.index, s.values

plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('# of Heat/Hot Water Complaints')
plt.show()
```

Output will look like this:

[image]

Comment: This is a different type of plot . i have to define xdata,ydata because I will later on use machine learning model to predict future of complaints and with this plot I cannot do that.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense now